Imitate Evince "copy image" resulting image. Which is copying only the text part of the image
I have a PDF which allows me to "copy image" in Evince and the result is looks like the first image. (which is only copying the text and leaving everything else transparent)
If I open a page in Inkspace the text is also separated from the background. The original pdf looks like the second.
I have tried to use cpdf -draft and cpdf -blacktext on it, but I only get an absolute white pdf with selectable and copiable invisible text.
In reality I would like to imitate the Evince resulting image from "copy image."


